# Simple XML Framework: nothing required by default

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

How can I set **all** elements/attributes to `required="false"` in Simple XML Framework? My class starts with

```
@Root
@Default(DefaultType.FIELD)
```

But things like `@Root(required=false)` or `@Default(DefaultType.FIELD, required=false)` did not work.

I know I can add the required flag anywhere I want by hand, regex or AspectJ, but I want to know if there is already a built-in functionality **to automatically set all elements/attributes to required=false as a default**.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Answer (score -3):

According to documentation and investigating code, it isn't possible.

But you can override annotations classes in your project, so it must looks like code bellow.

```
package org.simpleframework.xml;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Element {

    String name() default "";

    boolean data() default false;

    // HERE: using false
    boolean required() default false;

    Class type() default void.class;
}
```

Comment: I think I was misunderstood and tried to clarify my question